# Why does this keep returning the last value of the dictionary?

Tags: python

So i'm practicing my  nested dictionary skills with this data:

```
content = {'results': 
    [
        {'_class': 'question',
    'course': {'_class': 'course',
        'title': 'Angular 7 (formerly Angular 2) - The Complete Guide',
        'url': '/the-complete-guide-to-angular-2/'},
    'replies': [{'_class': 'answer',
        'user': {'_class': 'user',
         'display_name': 'Maximilian'}}]},
        
        {'_class': 'question',
    'course': {'_class': 'course',
        'title': 'RUSTCRACEON',
        'url': '/the-holy-rust-book/'},
    'replies': [{'_class': 'answer',
        'user': {'_class': 'user',
         'display_name': 'Ella'}}]},
                    
        {'_class': 'question',
    'course': {'_class': 'course',
        'title': 'PHP ULTIMATE WEB GUIDE',
        'url': '/php-to-the-world/'},
    'replies': [{'_class': 'answer',
        'user': {'_class': 'user',
         'display_name': 'Rick_Sanchez'}}]},
        
        {'_class': 'question',
    'course': {'_class': 'course',
        'title': 'Javascript - The Complete Guide',
        'url': '/javascript291/'},
    'replies': [{'_class': 'answer',
        'user': {'_class': 'user',
         'display_name': 'Morty'}}]}
]}
```

I'm able to access the value in the `results` key using this and all is good:

```
question_access = content['results']
```

If I want to loop through the dictionaries inside the `results` key I use this:

```
for question_data in question_access:
    print(question_data)
```

Which gives me this.. all is good:

```
{'_class': 'question', 'course': {'_class': 'course', 'title': 'Angular 7 (formerly Angular 2) - The Complete Guide', 'url': '/the-complete-guide-to-angular-2/'}, 'replies': [{'_class': 'answer', 'user': {'_class': 'user', 'display_name': 'Maximilian'}}]}
{'_class': 'question', 'course': {'_class': 'course', 'title': 'RUSTCRACEON', 'url': '/the-holy-rust-book/'}, 'replies': [{'_class': 'answer', 'user': {'_class': 'user', 'display_name': 'Ella'}}]}
{'_class': 'question', 'course': {'_class': 'course', 'title': 'PHP ULTIMATE WEB GUIDE', 'url': '/php-to-the-world/'}, 'replies': [{'_class': 'answer', 'user': {'_class': 'user', 'display_name': 'Rick_Sanchez'}}]}
{'_class': 'question', 'course': {'_class': 'course', 'title': 'Javascript - The Complete Guide', 'url': '/javascript291/'}, 'replies': [{'_class': 'answer', 'user': {'_class': 'user', 'display_name': 'Morty'}}]}
```

## Problem

But now my problem is.. if I want to access the `replies` key in the `question_data` key, I keep getting the last `replies` value and not all of the values.

i.e:

```
replies_access = question_data['replies']
```

returns:

```
[{'_class': 'answer', 'user': {'_class': 'user', 'display_name': 'Morty'}}]
```

Shouldn't `replies_access = question_data['replies']` return all of the values that have the `replies` key and not only the last value? Or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `question_data` is one element only from the values, so accessing `['replies']` gives you one for sure, and if you keep saving it in the same variable, at the end, only the last one remain

You may use a list to collect the replies during the loop

```
replies = []
for question_data in question_access:
    replies_access = question_data['replies']
    replies.append(replies_access)

print(replies)

[[{'_class': 'answer', 'user': {'_class': 'user', 'display_name': 'Maximilian'}}], 
 [{'_class': 'answer', 'user': {'_class': 'user', 'display_name': 'Ella'}}], 
 [{'_class': 'answer', 'user': {'_class': 'user', 'display_name': 'Rick_Sanchez'}}], 
 [{'_class': 'answer', 'user': {'_class': 'user', 'display_name': 'Morty'}}]]
```

Comment: this actually makes sense.. thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

`replies_access = question_data['replies']` will assign the value of the current question_data to replies_access. Since you're in a for loop, you keep assigning the next replies value to replies_access. Therefore in the last iteration you assign the last replies object and that's what you get when you print. Instead, you can make a list comprehension or use append.

```
replies_access = list()
for question_data in question_access:
    replies_access.append(question_data['replies'])
```

or

```
replies_access = [ question_data['replies'] for question_data in question_access]
```

Comment: This makes sense and i like the alternative format of the for loop.. thanks!